# How do I limit matches with a vanilla javascript autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, django

I created a like/dislike functionality for my Django app.

It uses jQuery/ajax and works fine, but it breaks my Devbridge autocomplete search (https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete).

I've decided to replace the Devbridge autocomplete with a vanilla JS autocomplete from here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp.

The problem is I have over 10,000 items in my array, so when you type in the first few letters it produces 100s or thousands of matches.

I'd like to limit the number of matches. Any help is much appreciated. I've included what I'm guessing is the most relevant code. For the complete code just check out the link.

```
<script>
function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
  /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
  the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/

var currentFocus;
  /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
  inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
  var a, b, i, val = this.value;
  /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
  closeAllLists();
  if (!val) { return false;}
  currentFocus = -1;
  /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
  a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
  /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
  this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
  /*for each item in the array...*/
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
    if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
      /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
      b = document.createElement("DIV");
      /*make the matching letters bold:*/
      b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
      b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
      /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
      b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
      /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
      b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
          /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
          inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
          /*close the list of autocompleted values,
          (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
          closeAllLists();
      });
      a.appendChild(b);
    }
  }
  });
```

Comment: Can you please add more minimal and specific code and make your code more readable please ?

Comment: Not really. This question is difficult. Only a true Javascript expert will be able to answer it. Like I said, in my post to decrypt the entire code block you will probably have to visit the original page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is I have over 10,000 items in my array, so when you type in the first few letters it produces 100s or thousands of matches... I'd like to limit the number of matches.

So let's find out where it iterates the items in the array and add an upper limit to the number of items that can be added to the list

```
// This is where it loops all the items in the array
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    ...

    // This is the logic which will dictate if an item is added to the list
    if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Let's add a limit to the number of matches that can be added to the list by breaking out of the loop once an upper bound has been hit.

```
let maxMatches = 10;
let matches = 0;
// Stop this loop once maximum matches have been found
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    ...

    // This is the logic which will dictate if an item is added to the list
    if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
        // Another match has been found, increment counter
        matches = matches + 1;
        ...
    }

    // Break the loop if we hit max number of matches
    if (matches >= maxMatches) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Solved the problem. Awesome. Thank you!